# Understanding memory access in C

Tags: c, pointers

Consider the following:

```
int i;
i = 12;
```

Which will obviously not give any errors. However, the following does:

```
int *i;
*i = 12;

Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.
```

Why don't I have access to modify the integer? It's still in the process's address space right?

Comment: `int *i` does not allocate an integer, just a pointer to one. Then you proceed to dereference the pointer to the non existing integer to write to it, which will, rightly, not do anything good.

Comment: You could do this though:
`i = (int *) 6;`
But then still it won't be no good. Coz a pointer pointing at the neighbourhood dragon is never too good now, is it?

Answer (score 1):

You don't allocate memory for the integer, you just create a pointer. I.e. when you try to access whatever the pointer points at to set the value, the pointer does not point to any valid allocated memory.

Understanding memory on this basic level is a necessity if you want to learn C. I suggest you buy an introduction to C book, or look up tutorials online. One of many places to start is here: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c-tutorial.html

Comment: Thanks, I have actually read 2 books on C and C++, but this was never actually covered, or I didn't read properly.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a step.  When you say:

```
int *i;
```

What you have is a pointer to *an integer*.  Right now, it's not pointing to any integer in particular, which is why you can't dereference it and change the value.  You'll need to set `i` to something:

```
int j = 5;
i = &j;
```

Now, `i` is a pointer that points to the value of `j`, which is 5.  You can now change the value:

```
*i = 6; // j (which i points to) is now 6
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to the answers already mentioned, you either need to point the pointer to something, or allocate memory for the pointer so that is has space in memory to point to. You can do this:

```
int *i;
i = malloc(sizeof(int));
if(i == NULL) // or if(i == 0) or if(NULL == i) or whatever you prefer
    fprintf(stderr,"Some error blah blah\n")
*i = 5;
printf("i = %d\n",*i);
```

That would work as well. Just make sure if you use malloc to test for a null pointer after doing so, otherwise you could end up with problems later if for some strange reason you couldn't allocate the memory needed for an int.

Answer (score 0):

No, when you declare a pointer without allocating memory to it, you are not guaranteed to point at a valid address in the address space of the process. 
For example assume that it is a 32 bit pointer, your assumption would mean that every process has 4 GB of memory available. But you may not even have 4 GB physical memory in the computer. 
What actually happens when you allocate memory is that the CPU, or the virtual memory hardware, is set up so it can translate the virtual address in your program into a physical memory address.
You can read a little more about virtual memory in wikipedia, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory